# Canot install edb in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: qt, debugging, ubuntu

I have tried to follow the steps as mentioned in http://samiux.blogspot.in/2012/12/howto-install-edb-debugger-on-ubuntu.html however I am getting an error

main.cpp: In function ‘void {anonymous}::usage()’:
main.cpp:158:18: error: request for member ‘toLocal8Bit’ in ‘plugin->QObject::metaObject()->QMetaObject::className()’, which is of non-class type ‘const char*’
make[1]: *** [.release-shared/obj/main.o] Error 1

...while doing make. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just comment line 158 in file src/main.cpp